# In google script, is there a way to spawn a function and not wait for it to complete?

Tags: google-apps-script

At some point in my script I issue a REST command which posts data to an external DB (using UrlFetchApp). I know that this will take a hard 15 seconds and I am not interested in the return messages.
Is there a way to issue the command and continue my script without waiting?

Comment: I have the same issue. But ends up using Amazon SQS.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
  .create();
```

Refer:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)